# Getting Cesium to work with Webpacker and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, cesiumjs, webpacker

I'm trying to follow [these instructions](https://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/cesium-and-webpack/#add-cesium-to-a-webpack-app) to add cesium to my rails project with Webpack, but I can't figure out how to translate the instructions to work with the rails implementation of Webpack.

For example:

> In webpack.config.js, we add the following above our configuration object:
>
> // The path to the Cesium source code
>
> const cesiumSource = 'node_modules/cesium/Source';
>
> const cesiumWorkers = '../Build/Cesium/Workers';

I assume in a rails project we would do our file imports in `app/javascript/packs/application.js` like this:

```
import 'cesium/Source';
import 'cesium/Build/Cesium/Workers';
```

but that gives the error:

```
Failed to compile.

./app/javascript/packs/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cesium/Build/Cesium/Workers' in '/Users/user/Developer/appName/app/javascript/packs'
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 15:0-37
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
```

I've double checked, and the path is correct.

The Cesium instructions also indicate that I need to add some configuration options, but I can't figure out where I would put those since the rails webpacker gem doesn't have a `webpack.config.js` file. Do I just add config to the same file as the imports?

Answer (score 0):

You would rather add a new config file which resolve your libs custom paths.
You can get inspiration from Webpacker documentation here:
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md#configuration

You could do this :

```
//config/webpack/cesium.js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      cesiumSource: 'cesium/Source',
      cesiumWorkers: 'cesium/Build/Cesium/Workers'
    }
  }
}
```

Then merge the config options either in environment.js (global) or in development|test|production.js if this is specific to a particular environment

```
// config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const cesiumConfig = require('./cesium')
environment.config.merge(cesiumConfig)
```

Hope this help.
Regards